# REST API headers supported

Tags: rest, restful-url

I would like to understand available REST API legacy source code. I was wondering if there is some mechanism available to know all headers supported in legacy REST API.

Basically in webservices , we can just open WSDL and know all the methods available. What about in rest services, Is there any way to check REST headers supported through some way.

regards,

Comment: Can you tell us more about the Framework used to build the REST API? Are you able to do some modifications in order to have these informations or do you need a solution that do not modify your code?

Comment: I am going through Openstack SWIFT source code... there are some headers used which are not mentioned in its documentation..

Answer (score 0):

You might generate documentation if not exists. Check tools like [Swagger](https://helloreverb.com/developers/swagger).